# pd.to_datetime gives Timestamp objects and to_pydatetime does not work on it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am reading a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file_path")
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

When I want to access `df['time'].dt` in order to get `year`, `month`, etc. I get the error that:

`'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'`.

There are many posts on StackOverflow related to my question. I tried the suggested solutions which was using `to_pydatetime()` but it did not work. I appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: If you already have a `Timestamp`, just do `df['time'].year`.  You've already done the conversion.

Comment: @TimRoberts `df['time']` is a Series of Timestamps and when I use that I get the error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'` and that's why I need to work with `dt` so that I can call on all the instances of the Series.

Comment: But the error you cite says `'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'`.  Which is it?  A `Timestamp` or a `Series`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get/extract a parameter like hour or year of a Timestamp data type in pandas, you can use the methods with the name of the attribute.

Example:

- df['time].year
- df['time].month
- df['time'].day
- df['time].hour

ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.hour.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.year.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `df['time']` is a Series and `year, month, day, etc.` do not work on it.

Comment: for a series you can use the .dt

Answer (score 0):

OK, then, I'm confused about what code you actually have.  The error message you cite says that you have a `Timestamp` object, not a `Series`.  **IF** you have a `Series`, then you need `dt`.  If you have an individual element, then you do not need `dt`.  Here is a snippet based on your code that works perfectly.  If this is not what you have, then you need to modify the question.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
        '2019-06-06',
        '2020-04-01',
        '2021-01-01'
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time'] )
print(df)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
print(df)
print(df['time'].dt.year)
```

Output:

```
         time
0  2019-06-06
1  2020-04-01
2  2021-01-01
        time
0 2019-06-06
1 2020-04-01
2 2021-01-01
0    2019
1    2020
2    2021
Name: time, dtype: int64
```